# Allow only to pick some images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this picture where each square is a `img` element. I need to allow users to pick some combinations. The unique allowed combinations are:

- AD
- BC
- ABCD

So when user pick `A` I should disable click event on `B` and `C` but allow on `D` and the same with the others based on possible combinations. I know this [library](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) that can helps but don't have the idea to restrict selection. How I can achieve this?

[image: no description]

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results. - That being said, you can use the same class that the image picker uses and include a script that removes that class from an image if `A` is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the the creator of a plugin that seeks to solve a similar problem, it can be found here:

http://rvera.github.io/image-picker

Reyner also creater a github issue regarding this problem which can be found here:

https://github.com/rvera/image-picker/issues/19

A very simple example of how to solve this using the built-in callbacks can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7vyPt/7/

The basic idea is to use the built-in callbacks to define your logic, the code would look like this:

```
jQuery("select.image-picker").imagepicker({
    selected: function(option){
        var values = this.val();
        if (
            jQuery.inArray("dog", values) > -1 && 
            (jQuery.inArray("cat1", values) > -1 || 
             jQuery.inArray("cat2", values) > -1 ) )
        {
            alert("Can't mix cats and dogs!");
            values.splice(jQuery.inArray(option.value(), values), 1);
            this.val(values);
            this.data('picker').sync_picker_with_select();
        }
    }
});
```

In this example, we don't want to mix two types of options, cats and dogs. It can be easily extrapolated to solve the original problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right and your approach will work when I need to pick AB or CD but what about if I can pick also A or B or C or D or even ABCD? That's where my problem resides and I don't know how to deal with this

Comment: Well, that's the great part you basically can code any rules you want in Javascript. You got all the selected values and the newest addition, with that in mind you can modify the selected options as you wish. With that in mind, the order in which you pick the options should not be important and some of your rules collide with others, particularly ABCD with AD and BC. To solve this you might need to have an extra validation when you try to submit the form since that combination can only be solved when the user says he is done, not when he is still picking options

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hardwire the given rules. E.g., if B and C should be disabled, when A is clicked

```html
<img id="a" src="http://placehold.it/100x200"/>
<img id="b" src="http://placehold.it/100x200"/>
<img id="c" src="http://placehold.it/100x200"/>
<img id="d" src="http://placehold.it/100x200"/>
```

```js
function process_a() {
    $('#b, #c').css('border', '1px solid red');
    $('#b, #c').off('click');
}

$('#a').click(process_a);
$('#b').click(process_b);
$('#c').click(process_c);
$('#d').click(process_d);
```

See full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Np74y/)

Answer (score 0):

set same class name on image elements for certain combination

```
<img src="path/to/A.jpeg" class="comb1">
<img src="path/to/B.jpeg" class="comb2">
<img src="path/to/C.jpeg" class="comb2">
<img src="path/to/D.jpeg" class="comb1">
```

group jq elements elements

```
var comb1 = $('img .comb1'),
    comb2 = $('img .comb2');
```

bind or unbind

```
comb1
    .click(function(evt){
        comb2.off('click');
    });


comb2
    .click(function(evt){
        comb1.off('click');
    });
```

Now the problem comes when you have to bind again the click event on images
you can set a time out on certain time

```
setTimeout(function(){
    comb1
        .on('click');
    comb2
        .on('click');
    }, 1000)
```

Comment: The third case isn't allowed here since I can't never pick the four images in your approach